# The size in bytes is the same size but there is an error as it is not the same size

Tags: python, numpy, types

I get a parameter that looks like this:

```
param_get_indirect = np.array([[1.1304908, 1.0647957, 1., 0.97220206, 0.9649332, 0.8939871, 0.81870604, 0.73949486,0.73949486, 0.73949486]],dtype='float32')'
```

and I didn't successfully convert him to a specific dtype.

i get the size in bytes :

```
num = getsizeof(param_get_indirect.tobytes())
```

I write a dtype:

```
response_dtype = np.dtype([('a', 'u4'),
                                    ('b', 'u4'),
                                    ('c', 'u1', num - 8)])
```

and after I try convert:

```
response_tlv_array = np.array(np.frombuffer(param_get_indirect,dtype=np.dtype(response_dtype)))
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

Although I print both and got the same result:

```
print(response_dtype.itemsize)
print(getsizeof(param_get_indirect.tobytes()))
```

in the consol:

```
73
73
```

How can I find out the size and convert?

This is the complete code:

```
param_get_indirect = np.array([[1.1304908, 1.0647957, 1., 0.97220206, 0.9649332,
                                0.8939871, 0.81870604, 0.73949486, 0.73949486, 0.73949486]],
                               dtype='float32')

num = getsizeof(param_get_indirect.tobytes())

print(getsizeof(param_get_indirect.tobytes()))

response_dtype = np.dtype([('a', 'u4'),
                                    ('b', 'u4'),
                                    ('c', 'u1', num - 8)])
print(response_dtype.itemsize)

response_tlv_array = np.array(np.frombuffer(param_get_indirect,dtype=np.dtype(response_dtype)))
```

Comment: Make a clear [mcve] with actual and expected output.

Comment: I did it , it is ok?

Comment: @Ino Not really.  What ist `getsizeof()`?  If it is `sys.getsizeof()` then that's the wrong function.  That gets the Python object size, which may or may not include the actual array data. The output 73 is a hint that this is wrong because each float32 value has a size of 4 bytes.  You can't get an odd total size with float32 values.

Comment: Yes, I got it, so what do you suggest I do to convert?
 and How will I know how many bytes the parameter contains?

Comment: @lno A [mcve] should reproduce the problem when someone copies and pastes the code and runs it *with no changes*.  Having the correct imports, for example, would answer the "What is `getsizeof()`" question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the source array we can multiply the `size` (= the total number of elements) by the `itemsize` (= number of bytes of a single element).

The number of elements in field `"c"` of the result is then the number of bytes of the source minus the size of fields `"a"` and `"b"` divided by the item size of field `"c"`:

```py
import numpy as np

param_get_indirect = np.array(
    [
        [
            1.1304908,
            1.0647957,
            1,
            0.97220206,
            0.9649332,
            0.8939871,
            0.81870604,
            0.73949486,
            0.73949486,
            0.73949486,
        ]
    ],
    dtype="float32",
)

a_type = b_type = np.dtype("u4")
c_type = np.dtype("u1")
#
# The remaining number of "c"s after subtracting fields "a" and "b" from source
# size.
#
c_length = (
    (param_get_indirect.size * param_get_indirect.itemsize)
    - (a_type.itemsize + b_type.itemsize)
) // c_type.itemsize

response_tlv_array = np.frombuffer(
    param_get_indirect,
    dtype=[("a", a_type), ("b", b_type), ("c", c_type, c_length)],
)
print(response_tlv_array)
```

Output:

```
[(1066447852, 1065896762, [  0,   0, 128,  63,  60, 226, 120,  63, 221,   5, 119,  63,  87, 220, 100,  63, 184, 150,  81,  63, 137,  79,  61,  63, 137,  79,  61,  63, 137,  79,  61,  63])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `len()` instead of (presumably) `sys.getitemsize()`.  The latter returns the size of the *internal* Python object including implementation overhead.  `len()` will return the length you want, which should be the size of a float32 (4 bytes) times 10 which is 40.

```py
import numpy as np

param_get_indirect = np.array([[1.1304908, 1.0647957, 1., 0.97220206, 0.9649332,
                                0.8939871, 0.81870604, 0.73949486, 0.73949486, 0.73949486]],
                               dtype='float32')
num = len(param_get_indirect.tobytes())
print(len(param_get_indirect.tobytes()))
response_dtype = np.dtype([('a', 'u4'),
                                    ('b', 'u4'),
                                    ('c', 'u1', num - 8)])
print(response_dtype.itemsize)
response_tlv_array = np.array(np.frombuffer(param_get_indirect,dtype=np.dtype(response_dtype)))
print(response_tlv_array)
```

Output:

```
40
40
[(1066447852, 1065896762, [  0,   0, 128,  63,  60, 226, 120,  63, 221,   5, 119,  63,  87, 220, 100,  63, 184, 150,  81,  63, 137,  79,  61,  63, 137,  79,  61,  63, 137,  79,  61,  63])]
```

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering is due to the mismatch between the calculated size (num) and the size required for your structured dtype definition. The num value includes the size of the original buffer but doesn't take into account the padding required for the structured dtype. To resolve this, you should ensure that the size of the response_dtype matches the size of the original buffer.

```
param_get_indirect = np.array([[1.1304908, 1.0647957, 1., 0.97220206, 0.9649332,
                              0.8939871, 0.81870604, 0.73949486, 0.73949486, 0.73949486]],
                              dtype='float32')

# Calculate the size of the buffer
buffer_size = getsizeof(param_get_indirect.tobytes())

print("Buffer size:", buffer_size)

# Define the structured dtype with padding
response_dtype = np.dtype([('a', 'u4'),
                           ('b', 'u4'),
                           ('c', 'u1', buffer_size - 8)])

print("Response dtype item size:", response_dtype.itemsize)

# The structured dtype size should be a multiple of 8, as it has to align with the buffer size.
# Calculate the padding size to make it a multiple of 8.
padding = (8 - response_dtype.itemsize % 8) % 8

# Update the 'c' field with the correct size (including padding)
response_dtype = np.dtype([('a', 'u4'),
                           ('b', 'u4'),
                           ('c', 'u1', buffer_size - 8 - padding)])

print("Updated Response dtype item size:", response_dtype.itemsize)

# Now you can create the response array
response_tlv_array = np.array(np.frombuffer(param_get_indirect.tobytes(), dtype=np.dtype(response_dtype)))

# Check the size of the response array
print("Response array size:", response_tlv_array.size)

# Print the values
print(response_tlv_array)
```